# NPM Warnings - "... is also the name of a node core module."

Tags: node.js, warnings, package.json

My Node app constantly displays the following warnings when running `npm install`, or installing new modules. Am I declaring these modules unnecessarily somewhere or is this expected behaviour?

```
npm WARN package.json fs@0.0.2 fs is also the name of a node core module.
npm WARN package.json fs@0.0.2 No description
npm WARN package.json fs@0.0.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json fs@0.0.2 No README data
npm WARN package.json http@0.0.0 http is also the name of a node core module.
npm WARN package.json http@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json http@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json http@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json querystring@0.2.0 querystring is also the name of a node core module.
```

Comment: seems like you might have fs and http included in your package.json as dependances when you shouldn't. you don't need to depend/install core modules, they're always there.

Comment: do you have an npm-shrinkwrap that has these defined?

Comment: I was originally declaring these modules in the package.json, but I've removed it and it's still occurring. Is it possible it's cached somewhere?

Comment: Is there an npm-shrinkwrap in the folder?

Comment: No npm-shrinkwrap in the folder or in /node_modules

Comment: you could try executing `npm cache clean` to clear the cache, though... i don't expect that to fix your problem

Comment: Didn't fix it. Out of interest, do you get the same messages if you run npm install on a project that already has installed components?

Comment: No, I do not. (min-length)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71117/discussion-between-zoosrc-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 0):

These are things that can be done to fix

- Uninstall fs & reinstall fs
- npm cache clean
- Delete node_modules folder and rerun npm install